# How to load csv data in hive with some columns as partition?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Let's say I have a data like this

```
player_id, stat_id1, stat_id2, year,team_id
```

I can create a table like this in Hive and then load the data.

```
CREATE TABLE data
(`player_id` INT,stat_id1 INT,`stat_id2` INT,`year` int,`team_id` INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
;
```

Let's say I want to create two partitions year, team_id. How do I do that in hive? Is there any way I can change the command above to achieve that? or Do I have to follow some other procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Addition the partition clause in the DDL should create the 2 partitiions

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
`player_id` INT,
stat_id1 INT,
`stat_id2` INT,
`year` int,
`team_id` INT)
PARTITIONED BY (year int, team_id int)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
;
```

You might need to have the above table that you have as a staging table in order map your input data and then load the data fro that table into the new table to partition it using insert command.